# How to run different main classed based upon setting?

Tags: scala, sbt

While building a `build.sbt` file, say I have two main objects:

```
object A {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = { println("I'm A!") }
}
object B {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = { println("I'm B!") }
}
```

I want to call `B` when environment variable `RUN_B` is set otherwise just run the default -- `A`. Two questions:

- Can I configure a setting which then mainClass setting depends upon and routes accordingly?
- Can I configure a setting from an environment variable?

Comment: Why not create one main and have *that* class dispatch?

Comment: Application should has only one entry point. But inside it you can dispatch and call different classes depends on environmenta variables.

Comment: Because it's a play application and I don't know how to configure that main class any differently

Answer (score 1):

I kind of did something similar to this with the following code

```
lazy val stage = sys.props.getOrElse("stage", default = "dev")
lazy val selectedMain = stage match {
    case "dev" => Some("A")
    case _  => Some("B")
}

mainClass in (Compile, run) := selectedMain
```

You need to set sbt -Dstage=production and then sbt run for to kick the either main A or main B.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read the environment variable using Scala code inside the mainClass task.

```
mainClass in run := {
    Option(System.getenv("RUN_B")) match {
        case Some(_) => Some("com.myproject.main.B")
        case None  => Some("com.myproject.main.A")
    }
}
```

You can inspect the setting to see if everything works:

```
> show run::mainClass
[info] Some(com.myproject.main.A)
```